# Whats wrong with my Random?

Tags: java, random

Here's my import statement:

```
import java.util.*;
```

Here it is in main:

```
    Random Rand = new Random() ;
```

Here it is in a public void method :

```
            int a = 0 ; 
            while (!done) 
        { 
            int a = Rand.nextInt(10) ;
            if (debug) stuff ; 
            if (possibles[a]==1) done = true ; 
        }
```

Here's the error message i get:

```
    TicTacToe.java:85: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method nextInt(int)
    location: class Rand
                a = Rand.nextInt(10) ;
                        ^
```

Whats going wrong here? it seems like i've done everything right to me.

Comment: The color of the Rand variable should have given you a hint..

Comment: @Kasturi: that might be useful for experienced developers, but hardly a good hint for someone new to Java.

Comment: When you posted your code, *classes* are the color *blue* and variables would be *black*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `Rand` in the `main` method and tried to use it on your *public void method*. It is out of scope.

Try defining `Rand` in the **same** method ( and use lowercase this time)

Something like:

in main:

<strike>Random Rand = new Random();</strike>

In your method:

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        int a = 0 ; 
        while (!done) { 
            int a = rand.nextInt(10) ; //<-- the one declared above
            if (debug){ stuff ; }
            if (possibles[a]==1){ done = true ; } 
        }
```

BTW use braces **always** even in 1 line if's

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you have defined a class called `Rand` somewhere in your project. Don't use this for a variable name. I'd suggest using `random` with a small r.

Also, this line is illegal:

```
int a - 0 ;
```

You should probably remove it as otherwise you are defining `a` twice.

Comment: i searched the file with the source code and the string "rand" (not case sensitive) only apears in the code that i have quoted in the question.

Comment: nevermind you were right before i think. I have a diferent class on my comptuer called Rand.

Comment: I bet the `int a - 0;` is actually a typo/c&p error. That would namely have produced another compilation error *before* the `Rand` error.

Comment: @David: The updated code should still not compile. It should give the error `a is already defined`. That line should be removed.

Comment: @David: in the future *please* **copypaste** the actual code from your IDE into the question. Don't type over or edit afterwards, as long as you're a bit green to the stuff :) Read on about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and [Smart Questions](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: @BalusC: My guess is that there are in fact many other errors before the Rand error and he just picked that one to post because it looked interesting.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> location: class Rand
> ```

You apparently have a **class** named `Rand` in the same package or in the imports. Rename the variable name from `Rand` to `rand` according to the [Sun Java Naming Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html) and it will <strike>work</strike> *fix the particular problem*.

Comment: It's a scope problem, not a shadowing problem.

Comment: @erickson: that's indeed one of many other problems to fix yet :) Do it step-by-step.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like `Rand` is a local variable in the `main` method.

It's not in scope when the "public void method" is invoked. So, the compiler is interpreting the identifier `Rand` as a class name. Coincidently, your class must be named `Rand`, so the compiler looks for a static method called `nextInt()`, and fails.

To fix it, you have a couple of options. Make the `Random` instance a local variable in the "public void method" that you created (by passing it as a parameter from the `main` method or other caller, or by instantiating within the method). Alternatively, you could declare a private static variable `Rand`. That variable would be in scope when invoking the method.

By the way, the convention for Java is that variables start with a lower-case letter. Types (classes, interface, and enums) start with a capital. Breaking this convention makes your code look really strange to a Java programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler told you the error was in `location: class Rand`.

Why does it think `Rand` is a class? Do you have a definition of `class Rand` in your code?

What happens if you call your `Random` object `r` instead of `Rand`?

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming Variable Rand to other name..

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that Java is looking for a method called `nextInt` taking an `int` on a **class** called `Rand`.

For some reason Java thinks that it has to look at that class instead of your variable. Is there a class called `Rand` in your program?

This kind of confusion can easily be avoided by following the naming conventions and starting variable names with a lower-case letter:

```
 Random rand = new Random(); 
 int a = rand.nextInt(10);
```