# non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static

First some code:

```
import java.util.*;
//...

class TicTacToe 
{
//...

public static void main (String[]arg) 
{ 

    Random Random = new Random() ; 
    toerunner () ; // this leads to a path of 
                   // methods that eventualy gets us to the rest of the code 
} 
//... 

public void CompTurn (int type, boolean debug) 
{ 
//...

        boolean done = true ; 
        int a = 0 ; 
        while (!done) 
        { 
            a = Random.nextInt(10) ;
            if (debug) { int i = 0 ; while (i<20) { System.out.print (a+", ") ; i++; }} 
            if (possibles[a]==1) done = true ; 
        } 
        this.board[a] = 2 ; 


}
//...

} //to close the class
```

Here is the error message:

```
TicTacToe.java:85: non-static method nextInt(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
            a = Random.nextInt(10) ;
                      ^
```

What exactly went wrong? What does that error message "non static method cannot be referenced from a  static context" mean?

Comment: `Random Random = new Random()` should be `Random random = new Random()`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694470/whats-wrong-with-my-random

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are calling `nextInt` statically by using `Random.nextInt`.

Instead, create a variable, `Random r = new Random();` and then call `r.nextInt(10)`.

It would be definitely worth while to check out:

- [What is the reason behind "non staticmethod cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-c)

#### Update:

You really should replace this line,

```
Random Random = new Random();
```

with something like this,

```
Random r = new Random();
```

If you use variable names as class names you'll run into a boat load of problems. Also as a Java convention, use lowercase names for variables. That might help avoid some confusion.

Comment: then i get a cannot find symbol error in regard to the r.

Comment: Did you initialize `r`? It can't just appear out of nowhere.

Comment: yes i replaced both the second "Random" in main (so that it reads Random r = new Random();) and the "Random" comming before "nextInt"

Comment: Remove the `Random` declaration from `main` unless you necessarily need it, and just initialize `Random r = new Random();` inside `CompTurn`

Comment: shouldn't i be able to create an instance of random inside main and then use it in other places?

Comment: I don't believe it is, once `main` runs it invokes `toerunner` which does whatever, so `toerunner` won't know that instance of random.

Comment: @David your main method declares `r` as a local variable, so it won't be accessible from the `CompTurn()` instance method.  In this case I'd say you should declare `r` as a static class field, e.g. `private static final Random r = new Random();`

Comment: isn't r an instance of Random though like an object? the syntax looks the same as creating an instance of an object.

Comment: Yes, it is, it is an object, but its scope is local to main, so it is not visible in other methods.

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I do this though (by calling the method with an object)...What do you think the problem is? Let me know if you need any code. Thanks! (Been stuck on this for 3 and a half hours now!)

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Without knowing the code you are using, we cannot supply you with an accurate answer. I would recommend searching this site for other similar questions to see if you can find the answer yourself; otherwise, I'd suggest opening up a new question and provide code and details of what you had attempted to try.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, static methods belong to the class rather than the instance. This means that you cannot call other instance methods from static methods unless they are called in an instance that you have initialized in that method.

Here's something you might want to do:

```
public class Foo
{
  public void fee()
  {
     //do stuff  
  }

  public static void main (String[]arg) 
  { 
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     foo.fee();
  } 
}
```

Notice that you are running an instance method from an instance that you've instantiated. You can't just call call a class instance method directly from a static method because there is no instance related to that static method.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to invoke an *instance method* on the class it self.

You should do:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a = 0 ; 
    while (!done) { 
        int a = rand.nextInt(10) ; 
    ....
```

Instead

As I told you here [stackoverflow.com/questions/2694470/whats-wrong...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694470/whats-wrong-with-my-random/2694516#2694516)

Comment: does it still work if i have the first line in mane? (see my comments on Anthony's answer).

Comment: In mane? Did you mean, in `main` ?? No, the random declared in `main` is local to that method. Once you get in a second method it is not reachable.

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I do this though (by calling the method with an object)...What do you think the problem is? Let me know if you need any code. Thanks! (Been stuck on this for 3 and a half hours now!)

Comment: @RuchirBaronia open a question and post your code, it should be easy to fix

Answer (score 0):

Violating the Java naming conventions (variable names and method names start with lowercase, class names start with uppercase) is contributing to your confusion.

The variable `Random` is only "in scope" inside the `main` method. It's not accessible to any methods called by `main`. When you return from `main`, the variable disappears (it's part of the stack frame).

If you want all of the methods of your class to use the same `Random` instance, declare a member variable:

```
class MyObj {
  private final Random random = new Random();
  public void compTurn() {
    while (true) {
      int a = random.nextInt(10);
      if (possibles[a] == 1) 
        break;
    }
  }
}
```