# non-static method generatePublic(KeySpec) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I am getting the above error in this particular line of code:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory=keyFactory.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);

        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec=new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        PrivateKey privateKey1=keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

To be precise this is the error I get:

```
GeneratePublicPrivateKeys.java:35: error: non-static method generatePublic(KeySp
ec) cannot be referenced from a static context
PublicKey publicKey1=KeyFactory.generatePublic(publicKey
Spec);
```

Note: I have gone through these posts
[“Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)
[non static method cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694566/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)
and some more and I have tried the solutions provided there,but no they do not solve my problem

What should I do?
Thankyou in advance:)

Comment: `keyFactory.generatePublic`, not `KeyFactory.generatePublic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
KeyFactory.generatePublic(...)
```

to be:

```
keyFactory.generatePublic(...)
```

At the moment your code is trying to call the `generatePublic` method as if it were static (ie associated with the KeyFactory class, rather than with an object of that type). You need to call this method on a specific instance of the class - presumably the `keyFactory` object refered to in your first code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
PublicKey publicKey1=KeyFactory.generatePublic(publicKey
Spec);
```

to

```
PublicKey publicKey1=keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKey
Spec);
```